# Get custom payment gateway data as settings in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment-method

I'm making a custom payment gateway. The complex parts are going fine but I've now been stuck on something stupid for hours.

I've created custom settings for the gateway without issue, they can be set and saved, but I can't figure out how to recall them in other functions.

If I place `var_dump($this->get_option('title'))` within the custom gateway class (which `extends WC_Payment_Gateway`) it will show correctly at the top of the settings page. Anywhere else, it won't. I've tried now hundreds of things, like trying to access this class by $this = new WC_Custom_Gateway, making the functions involved public, and utilising `init_settings()`.. I'm sure there is a very simple solution, but as a beginner I just cannot see it. I've tried examining the work of others to no avail also.

How can I make those settings available from outside the class where they are defined in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the following code will allow you to display the necessary data from your payment gateway settings using [WC_Payment_Gateways](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Payment_Gateways.html) and [WC_Payment_Gateway](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Payment_Gateway.html) methods this way:

```
// HERE define you payment gateway ID (from $this->id in your plugin code)
$payment_gateway_id = 'bacs';

// Get an instance of the WC_Payment_Gateways object
$payment_gateways   = WC_Payment_Gateways::instance();

// Get the desired WC_Payment_Gateway object
$payment_gateway    = $payment_gateways->payment_gateways()[$payment_gateway_id];

// Display saved Settings example:
echo '<p>Title: ' . $payment_gateway->title . '</p>';
echo '<p>Description: ' . $payment_gateway->description . '</p>';
echo '<p>Instructions: ' . $payment_gateway->instructions . '</p>';

// Display all the raw data for this payment gateway 
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $payment_gateway ); echo '</pre>';
```

Alternatively you can also use this shorter way:

```
// You will have to replace 'bacs' by your payment gateway ID (from $this->id in your plugin code)
$payment_gateway = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways()['bacs'];

// and so on …
```

Tested and works.

> You can also use some [WC_Payment_Gateway](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Payment_Gateway.html)  methods on `$payment_gateway`

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but this looks like exactly what I needed !! I never would have thought to try ::instance() , thank you so much !

Comment: The shorter way also works nicely: `$payment_gateway = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways()['bacs'];` (where you will replace "bacs' by your payment gateway Id)…

Comment: Additional question, if you/anyone has the time - what is the purpose of the middle section 'payment_gateways()'? Everything else is clear, but I don't understand what that part is doing, it's as if it's calling an object as a function but then also as an array?

Comment: `payment_gateways()` is the `WC_Payment_Gateways` method that will get specifically an array of all existing and defined `WC_Payment_Gateway` *(singular name class)* Objects

Comment: Oh okay, some labelling inception stuff going on there haha, thanks very much again !

Comment: +1 for `WC_Payment_Gateways::instance();` - I was using `new WC_Payment_Gateways()`, but that was rendering my actual `chosen` value useless. This will correctly get the _actual, current_ checkout gateway settings.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec You are the KING of the WOOCOMMERCE. thank you.